Create random partition inside a pandas dataframe and create a field that identifies partitions
I have created the following pandas dataframe:
ds = {'col1':[1.0,2.1,2.2,3.1,41,5.2,5.0,6.1,7.1,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)

The dataframe looks like this:
print(df)

   col1
0   1.0
1   2.1
2   2.2
3   3.1
4  41.0
5   5.2
6   5.0
7   6.1
8   7.1
9  10.0

I need to create a random 80% / 20% partition of the dataset and I also need to create a field (called buildFlag) which shows whether a record belongs to the 80% partition (buildFlag = 1) or belongs to the 20% partition (buildFlag = 0).
For example, the resulting dataframe would like like:
   col1  buildFlag
0   1.0          1
1   2.1          1
2   2.2          1
3   3.1          0
4  41.0          1
5   5.2          0
6   5.0          1
7   6.1          1
8   7.1          1
9  10.0          1

The buildFlag values are assigned randomly.
Can anyone help me, please?

SOLUTION (PANDAS + NUMPY)
A possible solution, which:

First, using np.random.choice to randomly choose 80% of df indices without replacement.

The df.index.isin function then checks each row's index to see if it was selected.

Finally, np.where assigns a 1 to the Flag column for selected indices and a 0 for the others.


df.assign(Flag=np.where(
    df.index.isin(np.random.choice(
        df.index, size=int(0.8 * len(df)), 
        replace=False)),
    1, 0))


SOLUTION (PANDAS + SKLEARN)
Alternatively, we can use  scikit-learn's train_test_split function:

First, it  randomly splits the df's indices into two groups: 80% for training and 20% for testing, as specified by test_size=0.2.

The training indices are extracted using [0]. The df.index.isin method then checks which indices belong to the training set, producing a boolean array.

Finally, this boolean array is converted to integers (1 for True and 0 for False) using .astype(int).


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df.assign(Flag = df.index.isin(
    train_test_split(df.index, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)[0]).astype(int))


Ouput:
   col1  Flag
0   1.0     0
1   2.1     1
2   2.2     1
3   3.1     1
4  41.0     1
5   5.2     1
6   5.0     1
7   6.1     1
8   7.1     1
9  10.0     0


Using sample and reindex:
df['buildFlag'] = (pd.Series(1, index=df.index)
                     .sample(frac=0.8)
                     .reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
                   )

Alternatively, if your indices are unique:
df['buildFlag'] = df.index.isin(df.sample(frac=0.8).index).astype(int)

Output:
   col1  buildFlag
0   1.0          1
1   2.1          1
2   2.2          1
3   3.1          1
4  41.0          1
5   5.2          1
6   5.0          0
7   6.1          1
8   7.1          0
9  10.0          1


You can use shuffle from random as well, e.g.,
from random import shuffle
v = ((df.index+1)/len(df)<=0.8).astype(int)
shuffle(v)
df['buildFlag'] = v

and the output looks like
   col1  buildFlag
0   1.0          1
1   2.1          1
2   2.2          1
3   3.1          1
4  41.0          0
5   5.2          1
6   5.0          1
7   6.1          1
8   7.1          0
9  10.0          1

